# Use visual diff to compare current repo vs master repo?

Tags: mercurial, diff, examdiff

We can use `hg in -vp` to compare our local repo to the master repo.

How can you do this visually?  We use the ExamDiff [extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ExtdiffExtension) as our Mercurial visual diff tool.  We figured there was a way to do the equivalent of `hg in -vp` but wasn't sure how to do this.

Comment: This question seems more suitable for http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hg diff` and its extensions are set up to compare versions *within* a repository, not for comparing different repositories so the easiest way to do this is to create a fresh local clone of the master, and use ExamDiff to compare that clone with your other local repo.

Comment: Is there a way to compare two repo's (not using diff)?

Comment: @Marcus: I'm not sure I understand the question.  I use Beyond Compare via the [ExtDiff extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ExtdiffExtension) for detailed differences between clones of a repository on a local file system, and `hg in` and `hg out` as a summary of the changes between them.

Comment: Basically I was looking for a way to do the diff without having to do a clone of the master..   was hoping there was a `hg diffrepo` command or something..

Answer (score 1):

You can use the non-bundled [`rdiff` extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RdiffExtension) (see the [answer to an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156280/using-mercurial-is-there-an-easy-way-to-diff-my-working-copy-with-the-tip-file-i/164566#164566)) to see textual diff.

None of the visual diff tools that I'm aware of (Beyond Compare, kdiff3, meld, DiffMerge) works over network. However if your repos are on the same LAN, it wouldn't be too difficult to write a small extension to find the divergent files between two changesets in two repos, extra them into a temp directory, and run visual diff there, which is basically what ExtDiff does within one repo.

[Niall C's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015275/mercurial-use-visual-diff-to-compare-current-repo-vs-master-repo/4015328#4015328) is still the preferred choice, since you'll need to pull master repo sooner or later (the sooner the better), so you may as well just pull and diff locally.